# I struggle to find data only by ID in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, axios

I'm trying to do a Pokedex to train on doing MERN app, i need assistance i tried so many solution

i struggle with finding the data by id.

When i try to find All my data on POSTMAN at localhost:4000/api/workouts/ it work fine, but when i try with specific id LIKE localhost:4000/api/workouts/1 it doesn't

Here is the error i'm getting : GET http://localhost:3000/api/workouts/1 404 (Not Found)

Error retrieving Pokémon : pokemon-detail.tsx:29 Error while retrieving the Pokémon: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

I tried to change many time the URL on the axios.get, on the road, but it can't find any data

so Here is my app url :

```
app.use('/api/workouts', workoutRoutes)
```

my router :

```
router.get('/:id', getWorkout)
```

the Controller :

```
const getWorkout = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const workout = await Workout.findOne({ id: req.params.id });
  
      if (!workout) { 
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Workout not found' });
      }
  
      res.json(workout);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  };
```

the onClick event i put on everycard to enter url with data of the pokemon :

```
const goToPokemon = (id: number) => {
    history(`/${id}`);
  };
```

The useEffect with a axios.get to get the data of the pokemon :

```
type Params = { id: string };

interface Workout {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  hp: number;
  cp: number;
  picture: string;
  types: string[];
}

const PokemonsDetail: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [workout, setWorkout] = useState<Workout | null>(null);
  const { id } = useParams<Params>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkout = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/workouts/${id}`);
        setWorkout(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération du Pokémon :', error);
      }
    };

    fetchWorkout();
  }, [id]);
```

My road on app.js:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/:id" element={<PokemonsDetail />} />

  
</Routes>
```

And of course my Schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const workoutSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    hp: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    cp: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    picture: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    types: {
        type: [String],
        required: true,
    },
   
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Workout', workoutSchema);
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, i don't know if it's related to your issue but you said "localhost:4000/api/workouts/" works and "GET http://localhost:3000/api/workouts/1 404 (Not Found)" doesn't. Is it normal that you hit one time port 4000 and next time port 3000 ?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see that mongo id is an Object id and not just the string uuid. Because of that reason mongo is not resulting the output.Object id is a type of BSON format ie. Binary JSON format and To query the Object id, you need to pass the parameter as an ObjectId format i.e.

```
db.Workout.find({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) })
```

Hope that helps :)